# EC2 instance running apache tomcat port 8443 not accessible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tomcat7

I have a AWS EC2 ubuntu 14.04 machine and apache tomcat 7 is installed on that machine.
I deployed a web application on apache tomcat7 and started the server, I had an issue where EC2 machine running apache tomcat7 was not accessible from outside using the port 8080.
Then I figured that we have to https://serverfault.com/questions/666338/ec2-instance-running-apache-tomcat-not-accessible-from-outside/731513#731513 do this that is present in the link, then port 8080 worked.

Now the issue is SSL port 8443 does not work, if I hit my web application in this manner https://{ipaddress}:8443.

Note - I have generated a certificate using java keytool and configured in the Tomcat server.xml

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="/home/ubuntu/mycert.crt"
           keystorepass="*****" keyAlias="tomcat" />
```

And my EC2 Security Groups Inbound Configurations
[image]

Can someone let me know what Im doing wrong?

Comment: Can you connect on the local machine to https://localhost:8443?

Comment: No, I was not able to connect through local as well.

Comment: When I run "curl https://localhost:8443 " locally it gives me the following output -  
curl: (28) Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received

Comment: is there any error log in catalina.out?

Comment: Thank you Muilpp, after you told to look at the Catalina.out log, I found the issue i.e. In the <Connector  /> I mentioned above, tomcat7 has the property named as "keystorePass" supposed to tomcat6 "keystorepass".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into the Catalina.out log, I found the issue i.e. In the  I mentioned above, tomcat7 has the property named as "keystorePass" (P is capital in keystorePass) but in tomcat6 "keystorepass" also works.
Due to this issue, password was not getting rightly set.