# Tomcat 8.5 SSL config on AWS EC2 Linux AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, spring-security, java-8, ssl-certificate, tomcat8

I am trying to configure Godaddy SSL certificate on my AWS EC2 Linux AMI Instance. But whatever I try it just refuses the connection. However I have already opened the inbound 443 port in the security group.
I have configured it several time on LAMP but its first time on java so maybe I am missing something?

I followed this [Godaddy's tomcat guide](https://pk.godaddy.com/help/tomcat-generate-csrs-and-install-certificates-5239/) to setup the SSL on my instance. And I also read the below threads to overcome the problem but still its not working
1. [Install SSL on EC2 Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799947/install-ssl-on-ec2-tomcat-server)
2. [EC2 instance running apache tomcat port 8443 not accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33337684/ec2-instance-running-apache-tomcat-port-8443-not-accessible)

These are the steps I followed:
This is how I setup the tomcat keystore

```
keytool -keysize 2048 -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore tomcat.keystore

keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -alias tomcat -file csr.csr -keystore tomcat.keystore

sudo keytool -import -alias root -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file /etc/ssl/WSssl/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt

sudo keytool -import -alias intermed -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file /etc/ssl/WSssl/gdig2.crt.pem

sudo keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file /etc/ssl/WSssl/ab51xxxxx79.crt
```

Configured the key file on tomcat 8.5 server.xml

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />

<Connector 
       port="8443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="/home/ec2-user/tomcat.keystore" keystorePass="exxxxxxxxxxxxxM"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

IP Tables to redirect

```
sudo iptables -t nat -n -L PREROUTING --line-numbers
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    REDIRECT   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 redir ports 8443
2    REDIRECT   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 redir ports 8080
```

These are Security Group inbound rules, directly connected without my ec2 instance with any load balancer 
[Inbound Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdYJM.png)

This is the problem, it is refusing every Https request
[Refused Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9br9m.png)

And this is Godaddy certificate checker [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Am3ES.png)

I think the issue is with port because request is not even hitting to server. Can anyone point out any problem?

For clearification this is the specs: 
AWS EC2 running on Amazon Linux AMI
Java 8 , Tomcat 8.5 
 Spring MVC with Spring Security Project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it is working there was nothing wrong with the configurations itself. While reading `catalina.out` I found that tomcat was not able to read `tomcat.keystore` file due to user permissions.

**Learnings:** Always read the logs first 

**EDIT:** Anyone can use it as a guide for setting up SSL